# Watson Retrieve and Rank Questions Upload Failed

Tags: watson, retrieve-and-rank

I've been working on a project involving the Watson Retrieve and Rank service and it was acting normally until now. I managed to upload a number of documents and created roughly 50 questions to start off. Normally, I was able to upload the questions just fine, but now I keep getting an error saying "Questions upload Upload failed".

I have attempted to use different browsers and going into incognito mode, yet nothing seems to solve the issue. I either get the error or the upload questions animation plays endlessly. 
[This is what it looks like as I try to upload the questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUxEz.png)

If anyone could give some insight on how to approach this problem, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the entire error log?

Are you sure the solr cluster and collection are created correctly? The Standard Plan for this service only allow 7 rankers in the free plan. 
You can try it with a new instance of the service.

Are you sure your training data meet the requirements?

Training data requirements: 
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/training_data.html

Comment: I'm currently using the online interface so the only error it gives me is the "Questions upload Upload failed".
Thing is I did a few test files and test questions, like 3 files and 10 questions, and it all worked. I created more data using the same format, yet now it doesn't do anything.
After a few minutes, I do get this message ```WebSocket connection to 'wss://ibmwatson-rr-wsapi-prod.ng.bluemix.net/primus/?topic=mq%2F6c46f1d0-46…%2F%2B&auth=Basic%20dGVzdHVzZXI6dGVzdHBhc3N3b3Jk&_primuscb=1496338969445-0' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.```

Comment: If I click on the performance tab, I get a 500 error. ```ibmwatson-rr-tools.ng.bluemix.net/api/questions/ebb42090-46f2-11e7-8592-89dda52aa3cd/questions?counts=answerranking Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve and Rank wasn't working correctly on Wednesday and Thursday. But today its up and running properly.